# TextView AutoLink opens link even though you didn't click/press it

Tags: android, autolink

We have a AboutScreen in our Android App where we have a TextView with AutoLink enabled for web|phone|mail.

My problem is that the opening of the link (doesn't matter if web phone or mail) happens as soon as it recognizes any touch on it.

For example:
You touch down on the link and drag your finger away from it to some free space. Even though you didn't really click the link but dragged away instead, the link is opening.

Is there any way to resolve this?